# " IsoDep.get(tag)" returns null while debugging

Tags: android, mobile, nfc

Can any one please tell me the "science" behind this function

```
 `IsoDep.get(tag)`
```

as it is returning **null** even tag is read correctly.
I am running android application in eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean by "in Eclipse" in the Android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Do the below procedure.

1)Get the NFC tech tag i.e. not so difficult to find just use tag.getTechList() method.

2)Suppose the device support only one tech tag like NfcF

3)then use the android class for the NfcF Like below

```
   NfcF mifare = NfcF.get(tag);
        try {
            mifare.connect();
            if(mifare.isConnected()){
                byte[] historicalData=mifare.getManufacturer();
                return new String(historicalData, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Deepak", "IOException while writing MifareUltralight message...", e);
        }
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Enjoy Coding...

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#get%28android.nfc.Tag%29):

- Returns null if IsoDep was not enumerated in getTechList(). This
  indicates the tag does not support ISO-DEP.

It looks like the NFC tag that you're reading doesn't support IsoDep.

To find out what is supported use this method.

```
private static String debugTag(Tag tag)
{
    String str = "=== DEBUG TAG ===";
    for (String techListItem : tag.getTechList())
    {
        str += "\n" + techListItem;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Or try an app like [TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite); that will show you on the last tab the classes supported by Android for the tag.